# Asymptotic expansion of $f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{\sqrt{n}}$ at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, fourier-series

The function $$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin nx}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is odd, uniformly convergent on all intervals $[\epsilon,\pi]$ for $0 < \epsilon < \pi$. Hence $f$ is continuous on $(0,\pi]$. Moreover $f(0)=0$.

> Is there an [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) for $f$ at the origin?

Comment: @Winther Good question. An "equivalent" in French is the first term of an asymptotic expansion. I realized that "equivalent" in English doesn't have the same meaning!

Comment: Some rough calculation suggest a $1/\sqrt{x}$ growth towards $x=0$: $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}} \sim \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}{\rm d}n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(z)}{\sqrt{z}}{\rm d}z = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2z}}$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net How did you determine the interval of continuity?

Comment: @E.Nole A uniformly convergent series of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: A general asymptotic expansion for $\;\displaystyle\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(n^a x\right)}{n^b}\;$ was conjectured in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3695281).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function $f$ may be rewritten as a [Clausen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#General_definition) or the imaginary part of a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Relation_to_the_Polylogarithm) :
$$\tag{1}f(x)=\operatorname{S}_{1/2}(x)=\Im{\,\operatorname{Li}_{\,1/2}(e^{ix})}$$
(since the polygarithm is defined as $\;\displaystyle\operatorname{Li}_{s}(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {z^n}{n^s}\;$)

We may then use the [DLMF expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12#E12) in $\,\log(z)=ix$ applied at $s=\frac 12$ :
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Li}_{s}(e^{ix})&=\Gamma(1-s)(-ix)^{s-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\zeta(s-n)\frac{(ix)^n}{n!}\\
\tag{2}\operatorname{Li}_{1/2}(e^{ix})&=\sqrt{\pi}(-ix)^{-1/2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\zeta\left(\frac 12-n\right)\frac{(ix)^n}{n!}\\
\end{align}
to get the equivalence (as obtained by Winther) by taking the imaginary part as $x\to 0$ :
$$\tag{3}f(x)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\,x}},\quad x\to 0$$
and the expansion (keeping only the terms $n=2k+1$) :
$$\tag{4}f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\,x}}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\zeta\left(-\frac 12-2k\right)\frac{(-1)^k\,x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Comment: interesting, the euler mac-laurin formula suggests a subleading term $sin(x)/2$ which somehow doesen't fit exactly to ur expansion.